# Images disappearing with alert

Tags: reactjs, react-native

### Description

When the application fires an alert (From the Alert namespace), all local images rendered on the screen disappear on iOS.

### React Native version:

0.63.2
Expo SDK v40.0.0

### Steps To Reproduce

Provide a detailed list of steps that reproduce the issue.

1. Create an expo snack
2. Create a Pressable component (Pressable, Button, TouchableOpacity, etc...)
3. Create an image
4. Set the onPress prop to call a function that fires an alert.
5. Switch to the iOS tab and click Tap to Play

### Expected Results

The alert fires and the image stays rendered on the screen

### Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository:

[https://snack.expo.io/@razorshnegax/1f5b93'](https://snack.expo.io/@razorshnegax/1f5b93%27)

Code Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, Image, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            let eer = 'ees';
            // Fires the alert
            Alert.alert(eer);
          }}
          title="yeep"
        />
        // The image that dissappears
        <Image source={require('./image.gif')} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Running code an a sandbox/snack is great but you should still include the relevant code with issue here in your question so it is persisted with the question.

Comment: @DrewReese I added a code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using a 'gif', not an image. Image from `react-native` doesn't support gif in iOS.
[Source](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.62/image).

If you replace it with a png file, it won't disappear.